# Microsoft Word - How to write left to right before a vertical line?

Tags: microsoft-word

How to make the text left to right? And how to write something to the right of the vertical line? Also how to make the line space between the text too less like shown in the screenshot?

Here is what I want to achieve, couldn't put it in words.

[image]

Screenshot of the my attempt and the problems with it.

[image]

I could use spaces to make the text go to the right. But still I wouldn't be able to type next to the vertical line and also the line space is too much.

[image]

Comment: How did you introduce the vertical line? What is found to its left and right?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of drawing the vertical line, what I would do is

1. Create a table with two cells
2. Remove all external borders - you now have a vertical line
3. On the left cell, right justify the text
4. On the right cell, left justify the text

You don't have to mess about with spaces.  If you wish to introduce another item on the left, add a new row and remove the top and bottom borders.

**Edit**

For the blue circle, insert/shapes find a circle, add it where it is needed and fill it with the appropriate colour.  Note that the shape will be anchored (you may see an anchor symbol when the shape is selected.  This means that the shape will follow the paragraph it is anchored to.

Comment: @yokki Edited answer to add circle

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. The main thing I would have to revisit is the situation where there is still too much space on either side of the line.

If you do not have a vertical line + circle shape to start with,

- Insert and size the vertical line.
- Insert and size the circle. Make its fill white and its outline the same weight as the line.
- Select the two shapes and use *Shape Format -> Arrange -> Align* to *Align Center*
- Ensure the circle is vertically at the point you want on the line.
- Use Shape Format -> Arrange -> Group -> Group to create a single shape

Whether you already had a shape or you just made it,

- Right-click on the shape and use Wrap Text -> In Line With Text.

Leave the shape where it is, and create a one-row table with 3 cells.

- In Table Design -> Borders -> Borders, select No borders. Select the View gridlines option if you want to be able to work with the "invisible" Table
- With the Table selected, in Table Layout -> Alignment ->Cell Margins, set all the default cell margins to 0 (you may need to adjust this step later)
- drag the shape into the middle cell
- adjust the widths of the three cells so the line is in the correct position horizontally, and make the middle cell as narrow as you can
- select the left-hand cell and use Home -> Paragraph -> Right
- select the middle cell and use Home -> Paragraph -> Center
- select the right-hand cell and use Home -> Paragraph -> Left

Type and format your text. If it's too close to the shape, you can increase the width of the middle cell and/or modify the paragraph settings of the paragraphs in the left and right cells.

Answer (score 0):

**Use columns**

This assumes that the dividing line is provided elsewhere.

Begin with a blank document, switch to 'print layout' view and select Format > Columns…

Try the following settings (assumes six inches between margins — as you change one width, the others will change to fill the page):

- Number of columns: 2
- Equal column width: unchecked
- Width 1: 7.5 pi
- Spacing 1: 1 pi
- Width: 2: 27.5 pi
- Apply to: Whole document

Then enter your left-column text and format to flush right. Insert a column break after the text (Insert > Break > Column Break). The cursor will now be at the top of the right column. Enter your right-column text and format to Flush Left.

[image: At top, Columns dialogue box; at bottom, resulting word document.]

NB, checking the 'Line between' box provides a visual placeholder. I used picas here but use whatever suits you best.

If this formatting should not apply to the 'whole document' then at the appropriate place, insert a 'section break' and then set that section to 1 column. Note that after adding another section, this section's column formatting will change to indicate that it applies to 'this section' instead of 'whole document'.